# Can this expectation be computed?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Suppose I have some function $f(\bullet)$ and a random variable $X$ with known distribution (let us say for example $X$ has a geometric distribution with mean $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$).

I want to know: Is the expectation with respect to $X$ of the following summation easily computed?

$$\mathbb{E}_X\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^{X}f(k)\right].$$

Is it something like this when I use a random variable with geometric distribution:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha^kf(k)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient approach when dealing with sums of a random number of terms is to rewrite them as series, using indicator functions. For example,
$$
Y=\sum_{k=0}^Xf(k)
$$
is also
$$
Y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\,\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant k}.
$$
If $f$ is nonnegative or if the series converges, integrating both sides yields
$$
E(Y)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\,P(X\geqslant k).
$$

Answer (score 0):

For a geometric distribution with a probability of success $p$, the expected value is $$E(x)=\dfrac{1}{p}$$This formula can be easily obtained by using the summation formula of a geometric series.

Comment: **Hint:** For the expectation of a sum of a random number of terms, condition on the number of terms. This is double expectation. $E_X[\sum^N X_i] = E_N[ E_X[\sum^N X_i|N]]$. You also have constant summands, so $E[f(k)] = f(k)$.